# EDITED: JSP not opening from servlet using a database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Im having a problem in opening my JSP from my servlet.. i am trying to use my database to output it in my jsp.. I have also a class named Item.java to put it on the HashMap and put it to session to be able to use it on my next JSP..

here is my JSP that im trying to open

```
<%@page import="classes.Item"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%
String User = null;
HashMap<String,Item> currentInventory = null;

if(session.getAttribute("username") == null)
    response.sendRedirect("Login.html");

else 
{
    User = (String) session.getAttribute("username");

    if(session.getAttribute("currentInventory") != null)
    {
        currentInventory = (HashMap<String,Item>) session.getAttribute("currentInventory");
    }
}
%>

<%@include file="block/header.html"%>


<h2>Inventory List</h2>

<table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td>Stock ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>On Stock</td>       
   </tr>

<% 
   for(int i = 0; i < currentInventory.size(); i++)
   {
%>
   <tr>
     <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getStockID() %></td>
     <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getItemName() %></td>
     <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getUnitPrice() %></td>
     <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getOnStock() %></td>
   </tr>    
<% 

   }
%>

</table>

<%@include file="block/footer.html"%>
```

and here is my code in my Servlet

```
package servlets;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import classes.Item;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/ShowInventoryListServlet")
public class ShowInventoryListServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
   {
    HashMap<String,Item> currentInventory = new HashMap<String,Item>();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "password";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM items";

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if(rs.isBeforeFirst()) 
        {
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                String dbStockId = rs.getString("stockId");
                String dbItemName = rs.getString("itemName");
                float dbUnitPrice = Float.parseFloat(rs.getString("unitPrice"));
                int dbOnStock = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("onStock"));
                Item items = new Item(dbStockId,dbItemName,dbUnitPrice,dbOnStock);
                currentInventory.put(dbStockId, items);
            }

            session.setAttribute("currentInventory", currentInventory);
            String encodedURL = response.encodeRedirectURL("ShowInventoryList.jsp");
            response.sendRedirect(encodedURL);              
        } 

        else 
        {
            out.println("No records found...");
        }
    } 

    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        out.println("Error. Class not found...");
    } 

    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        out.println("Something wrong happened...");
    } 

    finally 
    {
        out.close();
        try 
        {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } 

        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

here is my Item.java Class

```
package classes;

public class Item 
{
    private String stockID;
    private String itemName;
    private float unitPrice;
    private int onStock;

    public Item(String stockID, String itemName, float unitPrice, int onStock) 
    {
       this.stockID = stockID;
       this.itemName = itemName;
       this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
       this.onStock = onStock;
    }

    public String getStockID()
    {
       return stockID;
    }

    public String getItemName() 
    {
       return itemName;
    }

    public float getUnitPrice()
    {
       return unitPrice;
    }

    public int getOnStock()
    {
       return onStock;
    }
}
```

error

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/MachineProblem] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /ShowInventoryList.jsp at line 41

```
    {
    %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getStockID() %></td>
       <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getItemName() %></td>
       <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getUnitPrice() %></td>
       <td><%= currentInventory.get(i).getOnStock() %></td>
```

Comment: ERROR: `at servlets.ShowInventoryListServlet.doGet(ShowInventoryListServlet.java:48)`.  SOLUTION: 1) look at line 48 of your doGet() method.  2) Determine what object is being referenced at line 48 ... and why it might be null.  3) Make sure that object is correctly initialized.  4) Or better,  change your code so that if the object doesn't initialize, it throws a meaningful error as to *why* it failed to initialize.

Comment: i already see the error thanks! but now i get this error

http://jsfiddle.net/dajwm2bb/1/

is there something wrong with my for loop?

Comment: Post the relevant code and error stack traces in your question. Not at jsfiddle. This is abusing both jsfiddle and stackoverflow.

Comment: already edit it.. im having problem editing the servlet so i cant post my code